# SQLAlchemy - Date range Gap Identifications, account for ranges that overlap

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to perform a self - join on a table, and look for all rows which match a set (state, office_type,office_class, district), in order to identify **ranges of dates** for which the set does not have data for.

My Current query :

```
term_alias = aliased(schema.Term, name='term_alias')
query = Session.query(schema.Term, term_alias).filter(schema.Term.office_type_id == term_alias.office_type_id).\
    filter(schema.Term.state_id == term_alias.state_id).\
    filter(schema.Term.office_class == term_alias.office_class).\
    filter(schema.Term.term_end < term_alias.term_begin).\
    filter(or_(schema.Term.district_id == term_alias.district_id,
               schema.Term.district_id == None)).\
    group_by(schema.Term.term_end).\
    group_by(schema.Term.state_id).\
    group_by(schema.Term.office_class).\
    group_by(schema.Term.office_type_id).\
    having(schema.Term.term_end < func.min(term_alias.term_begin)).\
    having((term_alias.term_begin - schema.Term.term_end) > 1)
```

The results I get, are not completely valid.

The Highlighted Row, should not be coming through.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, this is not actually a gap. The 1st term, and the 2nd term **overlap** and therefore should not be included as a gap

I have tried a few variations on the above query, but proper results have eluded me. My question is, how can I account for overlapped data? and ensure only true gaps are reported,

---

RAW SQL as printed by `print(query)`

```
SELECT terms.id AS terms_id, terms.term_begin AS terms_term_begin, terms.term_en
d AS terms_term_end, terms.term_served AS terms_term_served, terms.office_type_i
d AS terms_office_type_id, terms.person_id AS terms_person_id, terms.state_id AS
 terms_state_id, terms.district_id AS terms_district_id, terms.removal_reason_id
 AS terms_removal_reason_id, terms.political_party_id AS terms_political_party_i
d, terms.is_elected AS terms_is_elected, terms.is_holdover AS terms_is_holdover,
 terms.neat_race_id AS terms_neat_race_id, terms.office_class AS terms_office_cl
ass, terms.notes AS terms_notes, terms.is_vacant AS terms_is_vacant, term_alias.
id AS term_alias_id, term_alias.term_begin AS term_alias_term_begin, term_alias.
term_end AS term_alias_term_end, term_alias.term_served AS term_alias_term_serve
d, term_alias.office_type_id AS term_alias_office_type_id, term_alias.person_id
AS term_alias_person_id, term_alias.state_id AS term_alias_state_id, term_alias.
district_id AS term_alias_district_id, term_alias.removal_reason_id AS term_alia
s_removal_reason_id, term_alias.political_party_id AS term_alias_political_party
_id, term_alias.is_elected AS term_alias_is_elected, term_alias.is_holdover AS t
erm_alias_is_holdover, term_alias.neat_race_id AS term_alias_neat_race_id, term_
alias.office_class AS term_alias_office_class, term_alias.notes AS term_alias_no
tes, term_alias.is_vacant AS term_alias_is_vacant
FROM terms, terms AS term_alias
WHERE terms.office_type_id = term_alias.office_type_id AND terms.state_id = term
_alias.state_id AND terms.office_class = term_alias.office_class AND terms.term_
end < term_alias.term_begin AND (terms.district_id = term_alias.district_id OR t
erms.district_id IS NULL) GROUP BY terms.term_end, terms.state_id, terms.office_
class, terms.office_type_id
HAVING terms.term_end < min(term_alias.term_begin) AND term_alias.term_begin - t
erms.term_end > :param_1
```

SQLFiddle in its current state:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e030/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not able to handle overlaps, as can be seen from the simple comparison.

Looking at your data, I would perform search using following steps:

1. Find gap `begins`: by finding all such `Term` for which the day after `Term.term_end` is not *covered* by any other `Term` (of proper office_type/office_class/state/district)
2. For each found gap `begin` find a gap end by finding the earliest `Term` instance which starts after the gap `begin`.

I came to the following implementation:

```
TE = aliased(Term, name='TE')  # gap period start (end of last before gap)
TO = aliased(Term, name='TO')  # other term for check of TE
TS = aliased(Term, name='TS')  # start of the next period after gap

# condition for the existance of TE: no other periods overlaping with the next
# day after TE.term_end

# define an alias for the `TE.term_end + 1 day` (engine specific)
# gap_sdate = TE.term_end
gap_sdate = func.date(TE.term_end, text("'+1 days'"))  # sqlite version
# gap_sdate = func.ADDDATE(TE.term_end, 1))  # mysql version

# subquery which checks if there are Terms covering next day after term_end
subq = (
    session
    .query(TO.id)
    .filter(and_(
        TE.office_type_id == TO.office_type_id,
        TE.state_id == TO.state_id,
        or_(TE.district_id == TO.district_id,
            and_(TE.district_id == None, TO.district_id == None)
            ),
        TE.office_class == TO.office_class,
    ))
    .filter(TO.id != TE.id)
    .filter(TO.term_begin <= gap_sdate)
    .filter(or_(TO.term_end == None, TO.term_end >= gap_sdate))
)

# query to find the gaps
q = (
    session
    .query(
        TE.office_type_id,
        TE.state_id,
        TE.district_id,
        TE.office_class,
        gap_sdate.label("vacant_from"),
        func.date(func.min(TS.term_begin), text("'-1 days'")).label("vacant_till"),  # sqlite version
        # func.ADDDATE(func.min(TS.term_begin), -1).label("vacant_till"),  # mysql version
    )
    .join(TS, and_(
        TE.office_type_id == TS.office_type_id,
        TE.state_id == TS.state_id,
        or_(TE.district_id == TS.district_id,
            and_(TE.district_id == None, TS.district_id == None)
            ),
        TE.office_class == TS.office_class,
    ))
    # filters for gap start
    .filter(TE.term_end != None)
    .filter(~subq.exists())
    # filters for gap end
    .filter(TE.id != TS.id)
    .filter(TS.term_begin > gap_sdate)
    .group_by(TE)
)

gaps = q.all()
for gap in gaps:
    print(gap)
```

Comment: Wow!!!! I wasnt even getting close... I can't thank you enough for your assistance. it looks like it is working with minimal testing. I need to comb through all the work so that I can properly understand. Thanks again for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: Your comments and explanation are 10x better than anything I found else where. I wish I could give +1000. Thanks again.